# Why do Google Chrome downloads stay at 100% for a long time?

Tags: google-chrome, download

I've downloaded a 200MB file from Google Chrome. It took fairly short time for the download to reach 100% (a couple of minutes), but when it reached 100%, it stays at 100% for a long time before saying that the download is finished and renaming the file extension from .crdownload to the real extension of the file (in this case .zip). Why does the download go fairly quickly before reaching 100% and then stay at 100% for a long time?

Comment: Perhaps your anti-virus is checking the file?

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't have any anti-virus (I know, it's not safe, but it's not my computer so it's not my decision)

Comment: We have similar issues, but I don't believe it's any anti-virus program. The download freezes for a much longer time than it would take to do a scan.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Chrome itself is scanning/checking the files.

See:

[Disable chrome's built-in automatic virus scanning of downloaded files](https://superuser.com/questions/678601/disable-chromes-built-in-automatic-virus-scanning-of-downloaded-files)

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#safebrowsing-disable-download-protection

Comment: I wonder why they don´t display "Scanning for virusses" after completion, instead of acting like the download doesn´t work. It´s confusing for the user

Comment: Bonus question - why does it refuse to start new downloads while scanning one just finished?

Comment: We have similar issues, but I don't believe it's any anti-virus program. The download freezes for a much longer time than it would take to do a scan. More importantly, has the OP tried this to any success?

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I agree that it's erroneous behavior. On top of being confusing, it can take quite a long time on older computers.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug of some sort in newer versions of Chrome. My computer is definitely not old, and it takes a few minutes sometimes!

Comment: This is not a good transparent behavior of Chrome browser (and Google's part) at all. They should be clear about what they are doing with user's files!